# Required Set<String> but 'of' was inferred to ImmutableSet<E>

Tags: guava

I am trying to pass in a `Set<String>` in a constructor but I'm getting the following error:

```
Incompatible types. Required Set<String> but 'of' was inferred to ImmutableSet<E>: no instance(s) of type variable(s) E exist so that ImmutableSet<E> conforms to Set<String>
```

Here is the code:

```
final CustomMetricsModule customMetricsModule = new CustomMetricsModule(Collections.EMPTY_MAP,
                ImmutableSet.of("val", "val1"));
```

`CustomMetricsModule` has a map and `Set<String>` as its params.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was fixed by changing the `Set` that was imported. In `CustomMetricsModule`, I was supposed to be importing `java.util.Set`, but I wasn't.